# Blow up along codimension one closed subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose X is dimension two locally Noetherian scheme. Y is a closed subscheme of X, with codimension 1. Denote X' to be the blow up of X along Y. Prove that the structure morphism f:X'-->X is a finite morphism.

It suffices to show it's quasi-finite according to Zariski's main theorem. But I can't exclude the possibility that an irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y)$ maps to a closed point of Y.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's not true :

Let $X=Spec(A)$ with $A=k[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2-z^2)$ be a quadratic cone. Let $Y$ be a line through the origin of the cone : its ideal is $I=(z,x-y)$. We calculate :

$$X'=Proj_{A}A[t,u]/(zt-(x+y)u,(x-y)t-zu),$$ [**EDIT : THE FORMULA HAS BEEN CORRECTED**]

where, in the graded $A$-algebra $A+I+I^2+....$ we denoted $t$ and $u$ the degree one generators corresponding to $z$ and $x-y$.
Now, quotienting by $x$, $y$, and $z$, we calculate the fiber over the origin of this blow-up It is Proj(k[t,u]), which is a positive-dimensional projective line !

Comment: Here I take $Proj (\sum_{n>=0}I^n)$ as the definition of blowing up along V(I) on Spec A. So it is not always equal to $Proj_{A}A[t,u]/(zt-(x+y)u)$. More precisely, it is equal to $Proj_{A}A[t,u]/(zt-(x+y)u)$ when $Proj_{A}A[t,u]/(zt-(x+y)u)$ is integral. But here this expression is not an integral scheme. So this counterexample does not work under our definition of blowing up!

Comment:   We do have the same definition ! And $Proj_A A[t,u](zt−(x+y)u)$ is just the concrete expression of $Proj(\sum_{n\geq 0} I^n)$ in my example !

Comment: And after calculation, if you take $Proj (\sum_{n>=0}I^n)$ as the definition of blowing up, then you will see it's indeed quasi-finite in this example.

Comment: No, unfortunately. After localizing on the open set D(u), one would get (k[x,y,z,t]/(z^2-x^2-y^2, zt-(x-y)))_z = (k[y,z,t]/(z^2-y^2-(zt+y)^2))_z = k[z,z^{-1},t], and the fiber of the origin point is indeed finite. As you have seen, the point is that you need to take localization at D(z) if you take the definition as $Proj (\sum_{n>=0}I^n)$, but you don't localize if you take definition as $Proj_A A[t,u](zt−(x+y)u)$.

Comment: No, it's not. It is the union of two lines, the strict transform of $Y$, and another contracted to the origin by the blow-up as you can see from : 

$$Proj(\sum_{n\geq 0}I^n)=Proj (A/I)[t,u]/((x+y)u).$$

Comment: If you want to take the fiber over the origin of $k[x,y,z,t]/(z^2-x^2-y^2, zt-(x-y)))$, you just let $x=y=z=0$ and get $k[t]$, which is the line I'm talking about.

Comment: I see, you are right. I should not have localized on D(z). It is a subalgebra of A_z, but not need to localize. Thus this statement is indeed not true. Thank you!

Comment: Another way to see this example:  since $Y$ in $X$ is Cartier away from the singular point, the blow up of $X$ along $Y$ is the same as the blow up of $X$ along the intersection of the line with the singular locus - namely, the vertex of the cone.  Then you again see a projective line sitting over the vertex.

Comment: I don't think so ! In fact, the total space of the blow-up considered here is singular along the exceptional line, as you can see in the chart calculated by Taisong Jing, whereas the blow-up of the cone at the origin is smooth (it is the traditionnal resolution of singularities of the cone) !

Hence, these two blow-ups do not coincide.

Comment: I'm confused - is there something wrong with your presentation of the blowup algebra?  When $u \neq 0$, I calculate the open affine of your projective variety to be $k[x,y,z,t] / (x^2 - y^2 - z^2, zt - (x + y))$ (here I abuse notation and continue to use $t$ as the affine coordinate).  This is singular away from the line $Y$ I think.  Also I don't see the relevant calculation exactly by Taisong Jing.

Comment: I think the correct blow-up algebra should be $A[t,u]/(zt - (x+y)u, zu - (x - y)t)$

Comment: @Matt  Yes, you're so right ! It does'nt change the fact that the fiber over the origin is a projective line. However, and you were right about that too, the total space is smooth, and should coincide with the blow-up of the origin. Sorry about that. I will edit my post.

Answer (score -1):

How do you define blow-up? It should be straightforward to show that an explicit construction has relative dimension 0 over $X$.

**Update:** In the comments I suggest to take the formal two-dimensional ring $k[[x_1, x_2]]$ and work with it. This assumes that $X$ is smooth. If it's not, then Olivier gave an example of quadratic cone where blowup has relative dimension 1.

Comment: It can be resated algebraically as follows: A is Noetherian ring, I is a height one ideal, prove that $Proj (\sum_{n>=0} I^n/I^{n+1})$ --> $Spec A/I$ is a finite morphism.

Comment: I'm not good in commutative algebra, but you can reduce to $A$ being a formal ring `$k[[x_1, x_2]]$` and $I = (f)$, where $f$ is homogenious and then everything should follow.

Comment: No, you can't unless Y is a Cartier divisor. in this case X'=X... which is not very interesting !

Comment: Yes, just sa Oliver has said, the point is that the Weil divisor is not necessarily a Cartier divisor; and because we are not only considering algebraically varieties, so we cannot even have a good expectation of the normal locus on X.