# Blow up along codimension 1 subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. $Z$ be a closed subscheme of codimension $1$ (potentially with embedded points). $Z_{red}$ is a Cartier divisor and $Bl_{Z_{red}}X$ is just $X$. What about the blow up $Bl_ZX$ of $X$ along $Z$?

I am aware of the discussion in both [Blow up along codimension one closed subscheme](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10960/blow-up-along-codimension-one-closed-subscheme)
and [Blow-up along a subscheme and along its associated reduced closed subscheme](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90490/blow-up-along-a-subscheme-and-along-its-associated-reduced-closed-subscheme) and understand in general the blow up can exhibit wild behavior. I am wondering if the seemingly strong restrictions in my case changes the situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you compute any examples, e.g. $Z = V(xy, y^2)$ in $\mathbf{A}^2$?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Right, that's the first thing I should have tried before posting this...Sorry. Seems to be just the blow up of the origin in this case, no?